# how to get amount sum fields like this mysql query

Tags: mysql

I have a table like this, i want to sum the price fields,
Can it? total = 2000 !

| id | name | price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | me | 1000 1000 |

Comment: how your data is getting captured in price column?

Comment: Consider normalising your schema

Comment: How many values can be in `price`?  Is it always two?  Are they always separated by a space?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this problem will differ depending upon the number of items you have in the price column.

If the example you provided is the only case, and there are *two* items separated by a space, then this query will provide the result:

```
SELECT  id,
        name,
        Value1 + Value2 AS price
  FROM  (
        SELECT  id,
                name,
                SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, ' ', 1) AS Value1,
                SUBSTRING(price, LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(price, ' ', 1)) + 2) AS Value2
          FROM  myTable
        ) a
```

Output:

```
id    name    price
1     me      2000
```

The query splits the string into two by the space and then adds the values together to get the sum.

Note: If you have multiple values in `price` (i.e. more than two) then this query will not work.